# Formal Limit Proofs for Limits Involving Factorials

Tags: limits

How does one use the definition of the limit to formally prove that

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^4}{n^2 + n!} = 0?
$$

Comment: See also [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Answer (score 3):

n! > n^5 for n > 10. Then 0 < n^4/(n^2 + n!) < 1/n and you can use squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you know that $n! \ge n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4) \ge (n-4)^5$ (for $n >4$), so
you have $0 \le{n^4 \over n^2+n!} \le {n^4 \over n!} \le {n^4 \over (n-4)^5} = {{1 \over n} \over (1-{4 \over n})^5 }$. Hence for $n>8$ we have $(1-{4 \over n}) \ge {1 \over 2}$, and so ${n^4 \over n^2+n!} \le 2^5 {1 \over n}$.

Now choose $n > \max(8, {2^5 \over \epsilon})$, then ${n^4 \over n^2+n!} < \epsilon$.